How to profile memory in FastAPI endpoints?
I believe there is a memory leak in my deployed API, however I am struggling to find a straightforward way to profile the memory of the app. I have used profilers to find bottlenecks in endpoints without problem (just using: https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-cprofile/) - is there any simple middleware that can be added to show me if/where memory leaks may be occurring?
For context, here is a screenshot of the memory usage over time when deployed to a Kubernetes cluster via Docker:

I cannot seem to find any resources, but maybe I just haven't stumbled across the right place. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

I think it is not possible to profile memory in FastAPI endpoints directly, but you can use https://github.com/trallnag/prometheus-fastapi-instrumentator to gather basic metrics from your application, such as the number of requests received, which endpoints are used and how frequently, and the response status codes.
With these metrics and memory usage data, it will likely be easier to identify the cause of a memory leak.

Oh this looks super useful! Thank you so much. Totally going to set this up

Great that you found my answer useful. Was glad to help. Please mark it as the answer or upvote it when you have time so others can see that it helped you.
